# Can a c++ variadic macro read arguments spread over multiple lines?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20

I am trying to capture std::format style messages for application use in VS2019:

```
#define MyFunc(...) MsgProcessing( std::format( __VA_ARGS__ ) );
```

This works perfectly as long as the message fits on one line in the program. However, if the message continues on succeeding lines, if appears that the ellipsis doesn't understand to continue to the closing parenthesis, and stops at the end of the first line, resulting in predicable errors.

Does anyone know a way to capture a multi-line invocation such as:

```
MyFunc( "{} {}",
"Hello",
"world" );
```

Thanks!

I just tried my own fully reduced example, and as expected here, it works fine. There must be some interaction elsewhere preventing this from working in the larger system (it has lots of third-party inclusions). An odd symptom, but I'll move forward in a different way. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vhfEqM38o). Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally broke the line in the middle of a string literal?

Comment: Why would you even want this?

Comment: @TedLyngmo because it's tedious typing out `MsgProcessing(std::format(........))` every time you want to log something?

Comment: @M.M For logging where `__LINE__` etc. are used, I can see the use for a macro, but this looks like a normal function? Something like `template<class... Args> decltype(auto) MyFunc(Args&&... args) { return MsgProcessing( std::format(std::forward<Args(args)...) );`

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Not even for `__LINE__` because we have `std::source_location` now. (Granted, it sometimes requires little tricks to adhere to the default argument restriction.)

Comment: @chris True! I forgot about that nice addition. Bah... I see that I forgot a closing `}` on my replacement suggestion above :-/

Comment: This is the minimal reproducible example, in VS2019, using Latest as the language standard. It is a reduction of a proprietary logger whose purpose is to provide a simple api, i.e. MyFunc("Log {} here!",x);, while hiding necessary additional complexity, such as additional parameters required by MsgProcessing. These additional parameters to MsgProcessing are not parameters to the macro, so are not part of the problem, In VS2019, the code works when contained to a single line. When the ellipses covers a line broken between parameters (after a comma), the same code no longer compiles.

Comment: @Dinosaur, I can't reproduce this error under those exact conditions (and VS16.10 since you didn't specify further than major version). Obviously, though, I had to add code because the example isn't complete. This is the exact code I used and it compiled (but failed to link, which is expected): https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/conjTcYGz. Of course if the call is outside of a function, the compiler appropriately gives a different error regardless of whether the call is one line or more.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your macro in VS2019 and VS2022 and can't reproduce the problem - but that said, it's a macro and may be fragile in ways I wasn't able to discover.

I suggest a replacement in the form of a function template. This will work fine no matter how you break your lines - just as long as the syntax you use is correct.

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <utility>

template<class... Args>
decltype(auto) MyFunc(Args&&... args) {
    return MsgProcessing(std::format(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
};
```